# cURL: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds

Tags: php, curl

cURL gives me the error:

```
Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

In particular, the "0 milliseconds" part is suspicious...

My initialization code:

```
$curl = curl_init($requestUrl); // private URL not published
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
  array("Content-Type: application/xml", "Accept: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES, range(400, 599));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

The timeout seems correctly set, what may be related it?

Comment: What if you don't supply a timeout?

Comment: [Related curl issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/619).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, when tried to connect via https. Problem was with ssl version.
This worked well for me:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Comment: disabling host verification is smelly! And the TS already used `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`