# Send email via curl

Tags: bash, curl, terminal, smtp

I try to send a email via curl. and the following code dosen't work.

```
curl --connect-timeout 59 -v --insecure "smtps://smtp.live.com:25" -u "*****@outlook.com:*******" --mail-from "********@outlook.com" --mail-rcpt "*****@yahoo.de" -T mail.txt --ssl
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong? I wanna send the email via Outlook.com.

Comment: Hi! Probably you need to add more information here. As you only specify a curl utility parameters and this is probably not enough to identify what is going wrong. Please try to reshape your question, adding some more stack traces , error codes or log messages. Regards.

Comment: this is my output   `% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 65.55.176.126...
* Connected to smtp.live.com (65.55.176.126) port 25 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:58 --:--:--     0* Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received`

Answer (score 0):

After you have added more detailed output , it looks like ssl related issue,  the same symptoms are described here - [cURL: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485811/curl-operation-timed-out-after-0-milliseconds) , hopefully this helps.